# warning: ‘struct task_struct’ "Declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration"

Tags: c, struct, scope, header-files, declaration

I have the following piece of code:

**File sched.h**

```
   #ifndef __SCHED_H__
   #define __SCHED_H__
   #include <stats.h>
   truct task_struct {
       ...
       struct stats stat;
   };
   #endif
```

**File stats.h**

```
   #ifndef STATS_H
   #define STATS_H
   #include <sched.h>
   struct stats
   {
   ...
   };

   void initStats (struct task_struct* tsk);
   #endif
```

When I try to compile it gives me the following warning

> warning: ‘struct task_struct’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
> 17 | void initStats (struct task_struct* tsk);

I have seen similar questions posted, but I have not been able to fix the problem. I was wondering if the problem was because both files include each other. Any help would be appreciated : ).

Edit: I have changed a couple things in the code. Now, instead of using a task_struct as a parameter i am using a struct stats. But now the sched.h file cannot find the declaration of the struct stats. I have no idea on how this can be fixed. As the error the compiler gives me is different, I have posted a new question: [Problem with declaration of structs in header files: "error: field 'stat' has incimplete type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66930482/problem-with-declaration-of-structs-in-header-files-error-field-stat-has-in)

Comment: Don't you have any include guards in your headers? Will they really inconditionally always include each other circullarly? That is important information that is missing.

Comment: Your problem is caused by the circullar inclusion of your headers. If you include `sched.h` first, it will include `stats.h`. Assuming you do have include guards, in `stats.h` the compiler will reach the function declaration without seeing the declaration in `sched.h` before.

Comment: Try solving that circullar depenency or add forward declaration as mentioned in Vlad's answer.

Comment: Yes, they are included. Thanks for pointing out, i have already edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the previous declaration of the structure `struct task_struct` in the file scope is not visible at the point where the function is declared.

If so then in this function declaration

```
void initStats (struct task_struct* tsk);
```

the type specifier `struct task_struct` has the function prototype scope and is not visible outside the function prototype.

That is this type specifier is not the same as the type specifier

```
struct task_struct {
   ...
   struct stats stat;
```

};

declared outside the function prototype.

From the C Standard (6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers)

> 1. ...The same identifier can denote different entities at different points
>    in the program.

and

> 4. ...If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears
>    within the list of parameter declarations in a function
>    prototype (not part of a function definition), the identifier has
>    function prototype scope, which terminates at the end of the function
>    declarator

Here is a demonstrative program that reproduces the compiler message.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//  struct A;

void f( struct A );

struct A
{
    int x;
};

int main(void) 
{
    return 0;
}

prog.c:5:16: error: ‘struct A’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration [-Werror]
 void f( struct A );
                ^
```

If to uncomment the forward declaration

```
//  struct A;
```

then the error message will disappear.

Comment: Why is that happening? Shouldn't the program take the type specifier declared in the sched.h file as it is included? Why is it declaring a different one?

Comment: @shayminshaymin It seems that either there is a typo in your code and names of structures are not the same or the compiler does not see the previous structure declaration.

Comment: Seems like it is the latter. If I move the function to the sched.h file it doesnt give any warning or error.

Comment: What you showed in your example is what is happening, but i dont know how to fix it. I have changed a couple things in the code and I will post a new question about it. I will indicate this in the question itself.

Comment: @shayminshaymin You can close the question selecting the best answer and then ask a new question where you will provide a minimal complete program that reproduces the error.

Comment: @shayminshaymin It seems the problem occurred due to the recursive inclusion of headers in each other as it follows from your next question at SO.